# Palindrome method and comparison

Tags: java, methods, comparison, palindrome

In my program below - I have 2 classes and PalindromeTester is supposed to refer to the method findPalindrome in Palindrome. However, what is happening is that the value passed to the findPalindrome method is always returning a Entered string is not a palindrome, even when I test Strings such as level or mom or dad or madam.

Could some suggest a improvement? i'm quite sure that i think its my findPalindrome method that isn't examining the string right. I think its the method but if anyone sees anything else feel free to suggest. It takes the second to last character and tries to rebuild it, then compares it to the original string.

```
import java.util.Scanner;//import scanner class

public class PalindromeTester//class
{
   public static void main(String args[])//main method
   {
      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); //scanner object
      String palindrome = new String(); //string to accept user input

      String end = new String("q"); //string to determine user quitting

      for (int a = 0; a >= 0; a++){ //enter loop 
      System.out.println(); 
      System.out.println("Enter a string to check if it is a palindrome"); //ask for initial string 
      System.out.println(); 
      System.out.println("Continue entering strings until you are done. When you are done, enter q to quit."); //remind user to enter q to quit
      palindrome = in.nextLine();//take in string input
      Palindrome original = new Palindrome(palindrome); //palindrome object and passed palindrome to the constructor...but no value yet...so? 
      original = original.findPalindrome(); //call findPalindrome to determine if palindrome is a palindrome

      if (palindrome.equalsIgnoreCase(end)) //if palindrome is q and since end is q and if they are equal, a=-2.  
        a = -2; //when incrementing the max value if ++ will be -1. since -1 is not >= to 0 then for loop exits. 
      System.out.println("Thanks for trying this program"); 

     }  
   }
 }

_____________________________________________________________

    public class Palindrome { 
      String myPalindrome;  
      String myReverse; 

      public Palindrome(){
        myPalindrome = new String(""); 
        myReverse = new String(""); 
      }

      public Palindrome(String palindrome){
        myPalindrome = palindrome; 
      }

      public String findPalindrome (){

          int length = myPalindrome.length();

          for ( int i = length - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i-- )
             myReverse = myReverse + myPalindrome.charAt(i);

          if (myPalindrome.equals(myReverse))
            System.out.println("Entered string is a palindrome.");
          else
            System.out.println("Entered string is not a palindrome.");

          return (""); 
      }


    }
```

Comment: Did you try debugging it?

Comment: Please check the variable original, which is a type of Palindrome. And when findPalindrome() method is calling (original.findPalindrome()), it returns a String type. You can not do the following thing:  original = original.findPalindrome();

Comment: Does this code compile in first place?

Comment: You don't need to call `new String` in any of the places you have. You don't need a `Palindrome()` constructor (you don't call it) I suggest you return the message instead of always returning "".

Answer (score 1):

Your code fails to initialize myReverse when the string constructor is called. So it gets initialized to null and later appended with the palindrome string. You need to fix it. 
Having said that the above code cannot even compile and have many fundamental issues.

Comment: Wait...it does compile and one question? You do know that my code is 2 different programs sit by the line? According to drjava on my Mac it seems to compile fine? But I know why the my reverse object isn't initialized - because in PalindromeTester I only call on the constructor that accepts a string parameter.

Comment: Doesn't the following line throw any error? How can you assign a String to Palindrome? `Palindrome original = new Palindrome(palindrome); 
original = original.findPalindrome();`